# Create a list with all possible permutations from a know list of objects, but make the final list x in size

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation

Lets say I have the following list:

```
lst = [0,1,3,a,b,c]
```

I would like the final outcome to be all possible permutations of `lst`, but be 20 characters long.

I have looked and can only find examples that would create a final outcome that would be 6 or less in length.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by '20 characters long'?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to allow repetitions?  Then *permutations* isn't the word you're looking for.

Comment: If I have a list of 0 and a and I want it to be 3 characters long it would show me a string that is 3 characters and is every possible permutations based on 0 and a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you're looking for.

```
# A simple example
import itertools
lst = [0, 1]
print(list(itertools.product(lst, repeat=2)))
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Note that `itertools.product` itself returns an `itertools.product` object, not a list.

```
# In your case
import itertools
lst = [0, 1, 3, a, b, c]
output = list(itertools.product(lst, repeat=20))
```

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I wanted, but wow did my PC stutter when I ran your code. I guess asking for a 20 character string is to much. When I lowered it to 5 it looks like it gave me the right results. Thanks!

Comment: That's because the result is 6**20 = 3,656,158,440,062,976 permutations.

Comment: @MarkTolonen So how would I go about running code like that to get the 20 character string of all 6 inputs? Is there a faster way?

Comment: @George it would take far too much memory to store the results in a list. If you only need to iterate through them, then don't convert it to a list, and leave it as an `itertools.product` object.

Comment: @Volatility you nailed it on the head all 16GB of my ram was instantly used up and it started to page. I don't need it to be a list and am more interested in loading the results into a MySQL table.

Comment: You'll need a big MySQL table.  How many petabytes is your hard drive?  Also time.  Even generating one a nanosecond it would take >40 days.

Comment: @George I guess I'll ask the obvious question: Why the heck are you generating over a quadrillion permutations and then putting them in an SQL table!?

Comment: @Both of you. Well I have an idea that has to do with hashes and 20/6 was just a start the final string is 160 characters long with 16 inputs. Doing some math I'm looking at ~4.5e+192 rows. Not feasible on a desktop is it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want `all permutations`?  Assuming you want to reuse characters (not a permutation) that would be a list with a length of 6^20.

If you want one string of length 20 built from characters in that list, this should do the job:

```
from random import choice
''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(length))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that permutations and combinations (if you use itertools) follow the definition that each result can only physically exist if it is of equal or lesser length than the originating list.

If you are suggesting that you want one of the valid results to be "013abc013abc013abc01", then you'll have to modify your list to just be 20 items long and be made up of those 6 values.

```
from itertools import permutations
i = [0,1,3,'a','b','c',0,1,3,'a','b','c',0,1,3,'a','b','c',0,1]
results = []
for a in permutations(i, 20):
    results.append(a)
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking for (well, I sure hope not!). If each permutation took one byte, `results` takes more than 2 Exabytes. There will also be more 0s ond 1s than other characters.

Comment: I hope not either, but technically that's what permutations are. I don't think there will be more 0's and 1's though. Each result would be a length of 20, and each position would be made up of one of the available 6 characters.

Comment: There are 4 `0`s in your list, but there are only 3 `a`s. If `permutations` works like how I think it works, it should generate more `0`s than `a`s since each of the 4 are considered unique.

Answer (score 0):

`list(permutations(lst,x))` ; where `lst` is iterable (your input list) and `x` is the no of elements

for example:

```
In [8]: lst = [0, 1, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']

In [9]: from itertools import permutations

In [10]: result=[list(permutations(lst,x)) for x in range(1,len(lst))]
```